# jsf h:dataTable on 4 columns

Tags: jsf-2

i have the following simple code:

it print out some labels but it shows 
      only 2 columns

but in the panelGrid i have specified

```
  columns=4
```

i want 4 columns not 2.

the code:

```
        <p:tab title="Details Udfs" rendered="#{errorContractBean.flagMoneyD}">  
                    <h:panelGrid id="detailsudfM" columns="4" cellpadding="5" style="margin-bottom:5px" styleClass="grid">
                            <h:dataTable var="o" value="#{errorContractBean.liM}">
                            <h:column>
                                    <h:outputText value= "#{o.udf}"/>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                    <h:outputText  value= "#{o.value}" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
                            </h:column>
                           </h:dataTable>                           
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
```

current output:

[image]

desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `panelGrid` actually has 4 columns, but in the first row and the first column there is the datatable and the datatable has only 2 columns. I dont think that you should use a datatable here. Use the facelets `c:forEach`-tag instead. Try the following:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <c:forEach var="o" items="#{errorContractBean.liM}">
        <h:outputText value= "#{o.udf}"/>
        <h:outputText value= "#{o.value}" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: where come from the namespace c? i do not have it

Comment: This is the namespace for the JSTL core tags. Use `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`